# Uniform convergence of $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left (1 - \frac {z} {n} \right )$ on compact sets.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, infinite-product

> Does the infinite product $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left (1 - \frac {z} {n} \right )$ converge uniformly on compact sets?

I know that a necessary and sufficient condition for the convergence of an infinite product which is that the required product converges if and only if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \log \left (1 - \frac {z} {n} \right )$ converges. But I don't have any idea about the sum of the logarithm. Another simple sufficient condition is that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {|z|} {n}$ converges uniformly on compact sets which doesn't hold in this case since the harmonic series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {n}$ diverges. So how to deal with this problem? Any cooperation would be highly solicited.

Thanks in advance.

Rabin.

Comment: I believe you can get your answer from Ramanujan's lost note_part-II

Comment: @Polymath oh God! Could you please share some link where I can find it? Not sure whether I can able to understand it properly though.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee$:$ How to show that?

Comment: @Rabin Kumar Chakraborty chapter: Sums of Powers, Bernoulli Numbers, and the Gamma Function also you can he has mentioned this above problem too!

$$\prod(1-\frac z{n})$$ is available for sure!

Comment: Note that, if $n>|z|$, then $$\log\left(1-\frac{z}{n}\right) = -\frac{z}{n} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right). $$ So, if $z \notin \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, then as $N\to\infty$ we have $$\prod_{n=1}^{N}\left(1-\frac{z}{n}\right)=\exp\{-z \log N + \mathcal{O}(1)\}. $$ If in addition $z \neq 0$, then this diverges as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: @Polymath$:$ It will be more than helpful for me if you share some screenshot of the book.

Comment: @RabinKumarChakraborty sure! I'll try to add books link....(It's available online: *Springer*)

Comment: @Sangchul Lee$:$ I am not convinced to how do you get the sequence of partial product to be $\exp \left \{-z \log N + \mathcal {O} (1) \right \}.$ Could you please elaborate a little bit? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Putting this in another way, you can show that $$ \prod_{n=1}^{N} \left(1-\frac{z}{n}\right)e^{z/n} $$ converges as $N\to\infty$ for any $z$, and the limit is non-zero precisely when $z\neq1,2,3,\ldots$. (This is an example of Weierstrass product, and it is also closely related to the Gamma function.) Then the original product is $$ \prod_{n=1}^{N} \left(1-\frac{z}{n}\right) = e^{-z H_N} \prod_{n=1}^{N} \left(1-\frac{z}{n}\right)e^{z/n}, $$ where $H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$ is the harmonic number, which is asymptotically $\log n + \mathcal{O}(1)$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee$:$ Very nice argument. One another question I have in mind. How do I show that the product $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left (1 - \frac {z} {n} \right )$ or the product $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left (1 - \frac {z} {n} \right ) e^{\frac {z} {n}}$ converges to some **non-zero** complex number if $z \notin \mathbb N\ $? For $z \notin \mathbb N$ why doesn't the product approach $0\ $? Infinite product of non-zero numbers may be $0.$ Isn't it so?

Comment: You already know one sufficient condition for that, as you mentioned in your OP. :)

Comment: @Sangchul Lee$:$ Sorry, I don't get your point. My concern is not the convergence of the infinite product. What confuses me is that why can't the product you mentioned (in your penultimate comment) have a zero at non-integer points?

Comment: I am referring to the following [convergence criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria): $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges to a non-zero number if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log a_n$ converges. Applying this to $a_n=(1-\frac{z}{n})e^{z/n}$, the only obstruction for $\sum_n \log a_n$ to converge is that some $a_n$ becomes zero (hence $\log a_n$ becomes undefined). And you know exactly when this obstruction happens.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee$:$ I don't think that the only obstruction that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \log a_n$ converges is that $a_n = 0$ for some $n.$ There could be many other reasons for an infinite series to diverge. For instance if $a_n = \frac {1} {n}$ then neither of the $a_n$'s would actually be $0$ but $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \log a_n$ is divergent.

Comment: What you said is absolutely correct. My apology for being less clear, but in my comment I was talking about the particular choice $a_n=\left(1-\frac{z}{n}\right)e^{z/n}$, rather than about general sequences. If all the terms of this sequence are non-zero, then by noting $\log a_n=\mathcal{O}(n^{-2})$, we can prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log a_n$ converges (even absolutely!).

Comment: What I think since the product you mentioned converges uniformly on compact sets the limit function would be entire and hence any zero of it will have finite multiplicity. So in the factorization only finitely many factors will appear corresponding to the zero. Now apart from the non-vanishing exponential factor each term in the product is linear. Since these two factorizations match it should be the case that the factors which appear in the factorization of the entire function should also appear in the product in some order. But any such linear factor would correspond to a integer root.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee$:$ By showing that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \log a_n(z)$ converges uniformly on compact sets for $z \notin \mathbb N$ we can conclude that the product converges to a holomorphic function on $\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb N.$  Also at every natural number the product vanishes. So if we denote the product by $f(z)$ then there exists a holomorphic function $g$ on $\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb N$ such that $$f(z)= \begin{cases} g(z)& z \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb N\\ 0& z \in \mathbb N \end{cases}$$

Comment: @Sangchul Lee$:$ From here how do I conclude that $f$ is entire i.e. $f$ is also holomorphic at each natural number?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This may answer you with proper substitution

Comment: This is neither my answer nor I'm trying to answer it's in the request of OP's comment.